# Rails 3 Multiple Foreign Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

Im writing an app that has a user model, and the users in this model can be two different user types.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many        :transactions
  has_many        :transaction_details, :through => :transactions
  has_many        :renters, :class_name => "Transactions"
end
```

transaction.rb

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many        :transaction_details
  belongs_to      :user
  belongs_to      :renter, :class_name => "User"
end
```

transaction_detail.rb

```
class TransactionDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transaction
  belongs_to :inventory

  scope :all_open, where("transaction_details.checked_in_at is null")
  scope :all_closed, where("transaction_details.checked_in_at is not null")
end
```

Basically a user could be a renter, or the person checking the item out.  Once I have a transaction, I can call:

```
@transaction.renter.first_name  # receive the first name of the renter from the renter table
@transaction.user.first_name     # receive the first name of user who performed the transaction
```

This is perfect and works as I explected.  For the life of me, I can not figure out how to get the scope to work when called through a user:

```
# trying to perform the scrope "all_open", limted to the current user record, but I cant get it to use the 
# renter_id column instead of the user_id column
u.transaction_details.all_open
```

is this possible to have a scrope look up by the second forien_key instead of user_id?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - Yes. This is very possible.

You need to mention the foriegn key being used in the reverse association definition.

In users.rb:

```
has_many :rents, :class_name => "Transactions", :foreign_key => "renter_id"
```

This will allow you to write:

```
User.find(5).rents # array of transactions where user was renter
```

If you want to call the transaction_details directly, then once again you would need to specify another association in user.rb:

```
has_many :rent_transaction_details, :through => :rents, :source => "TranactionDetail"
```

Which would allow you to call:

```
User.find(5).rent_transaction_details.all_open
```